# Lvalue with [:] Python, does the Rvalue matter when assigning all the contents in a list?

Tags: python

Take:

```
my_list[:] = my_other_list[:]

my_list[:] = my_other_list

my_list[i:j] = my_other_list

my_list[i:j] = my_other_list[:]
```

I haven't found any differences between two. Is there cases where there would be?

My expectation, generally, with lists on the right hand side is that the left hand side is assigned to reference the right hand list itself, but this seems to be a special case.

Comment: They are functionally identical, but `my_other_list[:]` performs worse than `my_other_list` because it unnecessarily makes a copy of the list when the origial list would do.

Comment: So unlike regular assignment `a = b`, when I do `a[:] = b`, it is only the contents of `b` that get assigned? For some reason, I would've expected that this would create a nested list, replacing the contents of `a` with the list `b`.

Comment: In a slice assignment, the value on the right is treated as an iterable and is iterated over to generate items to assign to the slice on the left at corresponding indices. No nesting is involved.